# Regex specific word after equals sign

Tags: regex, netbeans

Problem is to find and replace word throughout file.  I'm trying to rename several fields but not edit the system names for those fields.  In the end, need to find/replace the Issue, Issues, issue, issues.  I'm using Netbeans (find and replace regex) to open the .properties file which contains this code, but open to using something else.

Text to right side of equals sign needs to be replaced. Sometimes there are periods next to the word on the right, most of the time there aren't.  Trying to use regex because there are around 10000 lines in the file (this is to the display text of system fields without changing the field reference itself).

Example of text to be searched:

```
issue.columns.admin.title=Issue Navigator Default Columns

browseproject.issues.by.status.more=View these issues in the Issue Navigator 
sorted by Status

issue.operations.voting.resolved=You cannot vote or change your vote on 
resolved issues.
```

Using the following as a pattern in netbeans, which gets around 90% correct.

```
(?<!([=.[a-z]]))issue(?!([[a-z]]))
```

However, it also matches the 'issue.' in fields like 'issue.operations.voting.resolved', which means that finding and replacing would cause problems by changing reference to the system fields. Is there a way to add to what I have already done to make it match words with periods appearing after the equals sign but not before?

Comment: Maybe you need [`(?i)(\G(?!^)|^[^=\n\r]*=)(.*?)\bissues?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tD4jCF/1)

Comment: Did that comment help?

Comment: Yes, extremely helpful.  I don't know for sure but it looks like this resolves my issue :)  Thank you for linking to a live version where I could see it in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)(\G(?!^)|^[^=\n\r]*=)(.*?)\bissues?\b
```

Replace with `$1$2<SOME_REPLACEMENT>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD4jCF/1).

It matches:

- `(?i)` - an inline case insensitive modifier making the pattern case insensitive
- `(\G(?!^)|^[^=\n\r]*=)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): either the location after the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or the start of a line that is followed with 0+ chars other than `=` and line break chars and then a `=`
- `(.*?)` - Group 2  (referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of...
- `\bissues?\b` - a whole word `issue` or `issues`